# PHP Laravel trying to get YouTube ID for user

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am creating a website where I want people to access their account/data on my website, thru the current youtube account they are logged into. It is the YouTube ID that I will store in a DB. So the YouTube ID is what will be use as their login. 
I am using Socialite. Being a very newbie at this google auth stuff I can see I am totalling stuffing it up.

I also gather since I am never returning a webpage since I'm dd()ing my cookies never get stored either but that's a minor problem. That's why testCall doesn't work.

If someone has a simpler way I'd be totally gratefull.

Web.php

```
Route::get('login/google', 'TestController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/google/callback', 'TestController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::get('hi', 'TestController@testCall');
```

TestController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;
use Cookie;
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_YouTube;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
        Cookie::queue('google_id2', $user->id);
        Cookie::queue('google_token2', $user->token);
        // may want to write google+ id as cookie
        //return response($user->token)->cookie('google_token2',$user->token);
        dump("id=>".$user->token);
        dump("token=>".$user->id);
        $this->listYouTubeChannel($user->token);
    }

    public function listYouTubeChannel($token) {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('API Samples');
        $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl');
        // Set to name/location of your client_secrets.json file.
        $client->setAuthConfig('../client_secrets.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setAccessToken($token);
        // if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        //     $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());        
        // }
        $service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

        $params = array_filter(array('mine' => true));
        $response = $service->channels->listChannels('snippet,contentDetails,statistics',$params);

        dd($response);
    }

    public function testCall() {
        $id = Cookie::get('google_id2');
        dump("id=>".$id);
        $token = Cookie::get('google_token2');
        dump("token=>".$token);
        if (empty($token)) {
            return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
        }

        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->userFromToken($token);
        dump($user);
         $this->listYouTubeChannel($token);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) of Youtube API on how to implement the OAuth 2.0 Authorization. There is a [PHP sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/php) here that you can follow.

If you want to get the User ID of an account, then there are a lot of ways that you can use in obtaining here like by using channel ID. Just search it in stack overflow and you will find many solutions on it.

Comment: Yeah but that sample is for a command line implementation which is not what I need. infact some of the code is from that sample.